# Sync Sharepoint from Mac

Tags: onedrive-for-business, sync, mac-os-x, onedrive

if I am not mistaken, what I want is oneDrive Business sync of SharePoint files to my Mac (osMac Sierra).

I have installed the oneDrive business client ( Version 17.3.6798 (0207) ) (yes, I uninstalled all other oneDrive clients before) but it always syncs with my private oneDrive account.  Apparently I can add a business / sharepoint account, but when I go to Preferences --- Account, the dialog box gets bigger, i.e. presumably showing the options, but then immediately becomes smaller:

[image]

Both accounts are under the same email, and I am using at the moment a Virtual Machine just to sync my SharePoint account to my local drive!

Any suggestions how I can sync a SharePoint to my local drive on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Hi what I noticed is that if I open up the personal OneDrive Pill all the portals show up online under a company tab on the left. When I then hit the sync option from here the Documents can be synced directly from there to my home folderr on OSX.

If however, I open up the Sharepoint Pill and work directly with the portal sites the sync button there tries to connect to my desktop but nothing is synchronised.

So synchronisation only works via the OneDrive Pill and not The Sharepoint Pill.

I think therefore that the Office Support link needs to be updated until such time as Microsoft resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft has an article which explains the step by step process to step OneDrive sync client for MAC systems.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-on-macOS-eadddc4e-edc0-4982-9f50-2aef5038c307

I have not applied these steps as I don`t have MAC system.

Comment: As I am not an Administrator, I followed the instructions provided at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-on-Mac-OS-X-d11b9f29-00bb-4172-be39-997da46f913f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_noaccountsignedin (again) and still the same - no sync, only private oneDrive available.